# Foundation NSXMLParser missing

Tags: xamarin.ios, foundation

I am looking for Foundation.NSXMLParser withing the Xamarin ios framework, or the correlating Interface.
Can anyone shed some light where i can find that, it seems to be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 'BugZilla' thread regarding this, the Xamarin team made the decision to deliberately not bind it. If you look at the [thread here.](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29104) It should provide you with all the information that you need.

> Sebastien Pouliot 2015-04-15 08:30:46 UTC
>   Yes, this's was a known,
>   deliberate design decision not to expose both:
>
> - NSXMLParser; and
> - NSXMLParserDelegate
>
> as .NET provides several much better alternatives that also are cross
>   platforms with our other products.

Comment: Thats unfortunate, i have a Binding library depending on those.

Comment: I know, but evidently theres not a big enough use case to justify exposing them. =/